# Does the effect at Brewster's angle apply for all angles greater, or only at that angle?

Tags: optics, polarization, radio-frequency

Came across Brewster's angle while studying radio frequency propagation.  something I'm unclear about is whether or not the polarizing effect only happens at Brewster's angle, or if it continues for all angles great than Brewster's?

I'm trying to understand it's implication when it comes to radio links, especially point to point across water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Brewster angle, reflection coefficient is zero (minimum) for a parallel polarized wave. Partial polarization occurs at angles near the Brewster angle, but complete polarziation of the reflected wave only occurs at the Brewster angle.